# Does my abstract generic class implementation needs any change?

Tags: java, generics, abstract

I have an abstract generic class to define the method process to all subclasses. I have simplified my code. In real life it is not about animals and I have 4 extensions in parallel of the "AnimalController" and they all need the method process with their own ReturnType. For demonstration it looks like this:

**Simple CatData implementing simple AnimalData without any generic**

```
public interface AnimalData {
   public String getName();
}

public class CatData implements AnimalData {
    String name;
    int age;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**The abstract class AnimalController**

```
public abstract class AnimalController<T> {
    public abstract T process(T a);
}
```

**The CatController**

```
public class CatController extends AnimalController<CatData> {
   
    @Override
    public CatData process(CatData myCat) {
        myCat.setName("Jerry");
        return myCat;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CatController controller = new CatController();
        CatData cd = new CatData();
        AnimalData cd2 =  controller.process(cd);
        System.out.println("MyCat's name is " + cd2.getName());

    }
}
```

If you run this generic code you will see

```
MyCat's name is Jerry
```

My question and my thoughts are about the general benefit of the way I have implemented it so far. Or is there a "best practice way" to handle common things like that. Would it be better to define the interface in a different way, e.g generic. As I already told, I try to find a good idea how to build up my growing system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better practice when using generics in this case would be to ensure your generic type `T` in `AnimalController` implements your `AnimalData` interface. This would be a minor modification, shown in the following:

```java
public abstract class AnimalController<T extends AnimalData> {
    public abstract T process(T a);
}
```

Also note that interface methods in Java are public by default, meaning your visibility modifier is redundant. This again is a minor modification:

```java
public interface AnimalData {
    String getName();
}
```